# How to save a model instance asynchronously Django (using the 4.1 Django ORM asynchronous interface)

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, orm

Recently [Django 4.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/4.1/) has been released with a new [asynchronous ORM interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/4.1/#asynchronous-orm-interface). It's really cool. But I've been using it for a couple of weeks now and I found a usecase that made me stuck.

Im trying to replicate this behaviour in an asynchronous context:

```py
class Foo(m.Model):
    """
    Stores information about a Foo
    """
    name: Union[m.CharField, str] = m.CharField(max_length=49)


foo: Foo = Foo(name='bar')
foo.save()
```

First of all, the `acreate()` method does not solve my issue. I need to first create the model instance and then save it.
My guess approach -being consistent with the ORM interface- was to use `foo.asave()` but the method does not exists.

I'm trying to find a cleaner way to approach this rather than the [sync_to_async](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/async/#asgiref.sync.sync_to_async) method.

Thanks a lot for the help! ❤️

Comment: Currently the only way seems to be the `sync_to_async` method. You may try writing a model mixin that implements an `asave` method which hides that implementation detail, though.

Comment: `asave` was added in Django 4.2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects